# 【Vue.js】How to delete when adding a delete button to the item turned by v-for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js

### want to

I'm turning v-for in Vue.js to get items out of an array.

I want to put a delete button on each item and execute deletion by pressing the delete button.

I'm fetching items one by one with v-for, but I can't get the id to delete the item

### source

```
<template>
  <main>
    <section>
      <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>タイトル</th>
          <th>詳細</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        <tr v-for="latest_information in latest_informations">
          <td>{{ latest_information.title }}</td>
          <td>{{ latest_information.detail }}</td>
          <td>
            <button type="button" @click="onDeleteConfirmSend(latest_information)" >
              <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </section>
  </main>
</template>

<script>

export default {


  data() {
    return {
      latest_informations: {},
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setData(query) {
      this.$loading.load(this.$auth.api.get(`admin/latest_informations.json`, {params: query})
          .then(response => {
            this.latest_informations = response.data.latest_informations
          })
          .catch(err => {
            this.$errorHandlers.initial(err);
          }));
      console.log(latest_informations)
    },

    onDeleteConfirmSend(latest_information) {
      this.$auth.api.delete(`admin/latest_informations/${latest_information}.json`)
          .then(response => {
            this.$router.push({name: 'AdminLatestInformationIndex', query: {toast_type: 'deleted'}})
          })
          .catch(err => {
            this.$errorHandlers.initial(err);
          })
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.setData(this.$route.query);
  },
}
</script>
```

↓
log
Started DELETE "/api/v1/admin/latest_informations/[object%20Object].json"

### tried

Make a decision without deciding what to delete dynamically

```
    onDeleteConfirmSend(latest_information) {
      this.$auth.api.delete(`admin/latest_informations/4.json`)
          .then(response => {
            this.$router.push({name: 'AdminLatestInformationIndex', query: {toast_type: 'deleted'}})
          })
          .catch(err => {
            this.$errorHandlers.initial(err);
          })
    }
```

↓

I was able to delete it safely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`latest_information` is an object (based on its usage in the `v-for` body). The delete button's click handler passes the `latest_information` object to the delete function:

```html
<button type="button" @click="onDeleteConfirmSend(latest_information)">
```

But `onDeleteConfirmSend` tries to convert that object into a string (resulting in `[object Object]`), and inserts it into the `DELETE` endpoint URL:

```js
onDeleteConfirmSend(latest_information) {
  this.$auth.api.delete(`admin/latest_informations/${latest_information}.json`)
  //...                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

It looks like the endpoint actually expects a numeric identifier. Assuming that's represented by an `id` property, you could update your `click`-handler binding to pass that property to the delete function.

Also at this point, you should probably remove the item from the displayed list as well. You'll need the index of the item to `splice` it, so update your `click`-handler binding to pass the item's index:

```html
<template>
  <tr v-for="(latest_information, index) in latest_informations">
    ...
    <button type="button" @click="onDeleteConfirmSend(latest_information.id, index)">
    </button>
  </tr>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    onDeleteConfirmSend(id, index) {
      this.latest_informations.splice(index, 1)
      this.$auth.api.delete(`admin/latest_informations/${id}.json`)
      //...
    }                                       
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First off you are not deleting anything from your array in `onDeleteConfirmSend`. I am going to assume that somehow your data is updating (you can confirm this in vue devtools). If it is not, well you will need to delete the item from the array.

Therefore the next thing I would assume is the issue is that there is no key triggering a refresh of your v-list.

Typically you would bind it to an item in your array, however in this case I'd bind it to a computed property based on the length of your array.

```js
computed:{
   arr_len(){
      return this.latest_informations.length;
   }
}
```

Then in your template, add a `key` to regenerate your list.

```html
<tbody :key="arr_len">
   <!-- Your HTML -->
</tbody>
```